# Dynamically picking out fields from JSON?

Tags: ruby, json

I'm writing something to populate a device data repository by reading JSON output from an agent on servers. I've run into a snag I can't explain.

When working with the nic_bonds I get:

```
block (2 levels) in translate': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

at the line where `slaves =` is declared. When I change `["#{name}"]` to a hardcoded `['bond0']` I end up with what I'm looking for: `"bond0"=>"eth2,eth3"`.

When I use a similar pattern, working with the Ethernet ports using `["#{name}"]` seems to be fine.

What gives?

code:

```
class DeviceDataTranslator
  def initialize(device_data_collector, device_data_repo)
    @device_data_collector = device_data_collector
    @device_data_repo = device_data_repo
  end

  # translates data between tools
  def translate
    devices_input = @device_data_collector.get_devices_data
    devices_output = []

    # translate data for each node/device
    devices_input.each do |node|

      std_fields = {}
      custom_fields = {}

      # network
      interfaces = node['automatic']['network']['interfaces']
      ethernets = interfaces.select {|k, v| k.match(/^eth/)}
      ethernets.each do |name, data|
        eth_port = {}
        mac = node['automatic']['network'].keys.find {|k| k.include? "macaddress_#{name}"}
        eth_port["#{name}_mac"] = node['automatic']['network']["#{mac}"] unless !mac
        custom_fields.merge!(eth_port)
      end

      nic_bonds = interfaces.select {|k, v| k.match(/^bond/)}
      if nic_bonds
        nic_bonds.each do |name, data|
          bond = {}
          slaves = node['automatic']['ls']['bonding']["#{name}"]['slaves'].join(',')
          bond["#{name}"] = slaves
          custom_fields.merge!(bond)
        end
      end

      # combine fields & add to devices list
      device = [std_fields, custom_fields]
      devices_output.push(device)
    end

    # handoff to device data repo
    @device_data_repo.set_devices(devices_output)
  end
end
```

And the (reduced) JSON:

```
    {
      "automatic": {
        "network": {
          "interfaces": {
            "bond0": {
              "type": "bond",
              "number": "0",
              "mtu": "1500"
            },
          "default_interface": "bond0",
          "default_gateway": "x.x.x.x",
          "ipaddress_lo": "127.0.0.1",
          "ipaddress6_lo": "::1",
          "macaddress_eth2": "x-x-x-x-x-x",
          "macaddress_eth3": "x-x-x-x-x-x",
          "macaddress_eth0": "x-x-x-x-x-x",
          "macaddress_eth1": "x-x-x-x-x-x",
          "macaddress_bond0": "x-x-x-x-x-x",
          "ipaddress_bond0": "x.x.x.x"
        },
        "ls": {
          "bonding": {
            "bond0": {
              "slaves": [
                "eth2",
                "eth3"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: As a note, `"#{name}"` is equivalent to `name.to_s`, which, if `name` is a String already, is actually a really long way of saying `name`.

Comment: Have you tried outputting/debugging to see what the value of `name` is on just before the `slaves = ...` line?

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid. Please make sure that your input information is correct, otherwise people trying to help you have to work extra hard just to get your code and data to the point of being able to reproduce the problem. That discourages people from helping and answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
block (2 levels) in translate': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Expected when you use a key that doesn't exist.

> at the line where slaves = is declared. When I change ["#{name}"] to a hardcoded ['bond0'] I end up with what I'm looking for: "bond0"=>"eth2,eth3".

So clearly `name` is not `bond0`.

> When I use a similar pattern working with the ethernet ports using ["#{name}"] seems to be fine.
>
> What gives?

You have a bug somewhere. :)  I just ran your sample, with the provided JSON (had to fix a `}`), but it works fine.  Maybe you exorcised some bad data that is breaking your code?  Add statements like this:

```
p name
```

In your loops to see what's really in there.